# How to click on doughnut pie chart element using selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am Able to find the element of each section of this doughnut pie chart but click event gets performed in the center of the chart(empty inner circle), which does not have any action. I need to click on the colored ring part of the chart. Pls let me know if there are any solutions to it.
The following is the xpath iam using:

```
WebElement osTypeChart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='oscontainer']/div[1]//*[local-name()='svg']//*[local-name()='g'][1]//*[local-name()='g'][1]//*[local-name()='path'][2]"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(osTypeChart).click(osTypeChart).build().perform();
```

```html
<div id="oscontainer" config="ostypeChart" class="dynamicChartWidth chartHeight ng-isolate-scope" data-highcharts-chart="1"><div id="highcharts-jy24ja7-2" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 589px; height: 176px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root " style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="589" height="176" viewBox="0 0 589 176"><desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.14</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-jy24ja7-3"><rect x="0" y="0" width="569" height="159" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="589" height="176" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="10" y="15" width="569" height="159"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="10" y="15" width="569" height="159"></rect><g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(10,15) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;"><path fill="#045f80" d="M 152.23584471234318 -1.899998558473598 A 69.5 69.5 0 0 1 152.30534470639597 137.0999779637625 L 152.30534470639597 137.0999779637625 A 69.5 69.5 0 0 0 152.23584471234318 -1.899998558473598 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-0" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="rgb(4,95,128)" d="M 151.98584471234318 -1.4999985584735924 A 69.5 69.5 0 0 1 152.05534470639597 137.4999779637625 L 152.0332068238376 109.69998677825751 A 41.7 41.7 0 0 0 151.9915068274059 26.300000864915845 Z" transform="translate(0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 "></path><path fill="rgb(251,176,65)" d="M 151.98584471234318 137.49999855847358 A 69.5 69.5 0 0 1 151.90346589430402 -1.4999329579995901 L 151.9420795365824 26.30004022520024 A 41.7 41.7 0 0 0 151.9915068274059 109.69999913508416 Z" transform="translate(0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1 "></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-undefined " transform="translate(10,15) scale(1 1)"></g></g><g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(368,55)"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="211" height="47" visibility="visible"></rect><g><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-0" transform="translate(8,3)"><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15"><tspan>Linux ( 50.0%  : 1 devices)</tspan></text><rect x="2" y="4" width="12" height="12" fill="#045f80" rx="6" ry="6" class="highcharts-point"></rect></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-1" transform="translate(8,21)"><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Windows ( 50.0%  : 1 devices)</tspan></text><rect x="2" y="4" width="12" height="12" fill="#fbb041" rx="6" ry="6" class="highcharts-point"></rect></g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip highcharts-color-0" style="cursor:default;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(166,-9999)" opacity="0" visibility="visible"><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 86.5 0.5 C 89.5 0.5 89.5 0.5 89.5 3.5 L 89.5 44.5 C 89.5 47.5 89.5 47.5 86.5 47.5 L 50.5 47.5 44.5 53.5 38.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 86.5 0.5 C 89.5 0.5 89.5 0.5 89.5 3.5 L 89.5 44.5 C 89.5 47.5 89.5 47.5 86.5 47.5 L 50.5 47.5 44.5 53.5 38.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 86.5 0.5 C 89.5 0.5 89.5 0.5 89.5 3.5 L 89.5 44.5 C 89.5 47.5 89.5 47.5 86.5 47.5 L 50.5 47.5 44.5 53.5 38.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="rgba(247,247,247,0.85)" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 86.5 0.5 C 89.5 0.5 89.5 0.5 89.5 3.5 L 89.5 44.5 C 89.5 47.5 89.5 47.5 86.5 47.5 L 50.5 47.5 44.5 53.5 38.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" stroke="#045f80" stroke-width="1"></path><text x="8" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20"><tspan style="font-size: 10px">Linux</tspan><tspan style="fill:#045f80" x="8" dy="15">●</tspan><tspan dx="0"> Devices: </tspan><tspan style="font-weight:bold" dx="0">1</tspan></text></g></svg></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it clicks in the middle of the doughnut chart, that means you can get the location (coordinates) of your click (middle portion). Once you get the location, you can add/subtract from the coordinates to make it click in a new location.

If you want to make it an even better solution, get the element dimensions and calculate those adjustment numbers based off percentages.

Comment: If i get the coordinates and change them, will it be able to click on the same point for different display screens and resolutions or will it remain the same? Just wanted to know if the coordinates change as per screen size and resolution.

Comment: @BipinShetty I believe they do change with screen size and resolution, you can test it yourself. That's why I suggested calculating those numbers based off percentages, might make it a little more scale-able. You'll get the center of the element regardless of screen/resolution. The adding to those coordinates is the tricky part, hence the percentages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and time. i have taken the coordinates and adjusted the values and got them clicking on the chart ring successfully with a constant values set for the chart. But since the values are dynamically changing in my case with more additional components getting added, the chart boundaries for each component is also getting changed. This is making it more difficult to click on a particular section with a dynamically changing chart.